# Bloom strangely appears in a yellow colour

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

[image: Problem]
Hey,

For some reason the bloom is appearing as yellow, I am not entirely sure why the bloom is yellow, its not a blending problem and the code seems correct.

I have researched on this problem and knowone appears to have the same problem, I'm thinking it may be todo with the fbo texture filtering but I'm not to sure. I need some help.

Here is the code..

***Final Gather code***

```
#version 330 core

out vec4 FragColor;

in vec2 _texcoord;

in float color;

uniform sampler2D scene;
uniform sampler2D bloom;

uniform float bloom_intensity;

void main()
{              
    const float gamma = 1.3;
    float exposure = 1.0;

    vec3 hdrColor = texture(scene, _texcoord).rgb;      
    vec3 bloomColor = texture(bloom, _texcoord).rgb;

    hdrColor += bloomColor; /// bloom_intensity;

    // tone mapping
    vec3 result = vec3(1.0) - exp(-hdrColor * exposure);

    // also gamma correct while we're at it       
    result = pow(result, vec3(1.0 / gamma));

    FragColor = vec4(result, 1.0);
}
```

***Bloom in light fragment shader***

```
// final lighting calculations
    vec3 result = calc_directional_light(Diffuse, Specular, Metalness, AO);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        result += calc_point_light(pointLights[i], Diffuse, Specular);
        result += calc_spot_light(spotLights[i], Diffuse, Specular);
    }

    float brightness = dot(result, vec3(0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722));
    if(brightness > 0.7)
        BrightColor = vec4(result, 1.0);
    else 
        BrightColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    FragColor = vec4(result, 1.0);
```

***Bloom setup***

```
inline void Create(std::vector<GLuint> shader_programs, size_t width, size_t height, float intensity)
{
    _shader_programs = shader_programs;
    _intensity = intensity;

    _fbo = new Fbo(width, height, { new FboAttachment(width, height, GL_RGB16F, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0),
                                    new FboAttachment(width, height, GL_RGB16F, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1) }, true);

    _h_blur = new Fbo(width, height, { new FboAttachment(width, height, GL_RGB16F, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0) }, false);
    _v_blur = new Fbo(width, height, { new FboAttachment(width, height, GL_RGB16F, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0) }, false);

_u_texturemap[0] = glGetUniformLocation(_shader_programs[0], "textureMap");
_u_texturemap[1] = glGetUniformLocation(_shader_programs[1], "textureMap");

    _u_blurres[0] = glGetUniformLocation(_shader_programs[0], "blur_resolution");
    _u_blurres[1] = glGetUniformLocation(_shader_programs[0], "blur_resolution");
}
```

***Bloom Render***

```
inline virtual void Render()
    {
        _h_blur->Bind();
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glUseProgram(_shader_programs[0]);

        glUniform1i(_u_texturemap[0], 0);
        glUniform1f(_u_blurres[0], 128.0f);

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _fbo->GetAttachments()[1]->_texture);

        _screen_rect->Render(1);

        _h_blur->Unbind();

        _v_blur->Bind();
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glUseProgram(_shader_programs[1]);

        glUniform1i(_u_texturemap[1], 0);
        glUniform1f(_u_blurres[1], 128.0f);

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _h_blur->GetAttachments()[0]->_texture);

        _screen_rect->Render(1);

        _v_blur->Unbind();
    }
```

Comment: Not the answer, but I suggest trying out this graphics debugger: [RenderDoc](https://renderdoc.org/). It helps me a lot with similar issues.

Comment: Thanks alot, ill try it out

Comment: I will be stealing RenderDoc's code now. #CodeSloth